# Parse.com: subclassing ParseObject and calling getParseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using the parse.com Android SDK.  I have a table Foo with a pointer to the table Bar, and classes Foo and Bar that extend ParseObject.  In Foo, I have this method:

```
public void getBar(final GetCallback<Bar> callback){
    getParseObject("bar").fetchIfNeededInBackground(callback);
}
```

This is the error I get:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.parse.ParseObject cannot be cast to com.package.Bar`

`getParseObject` returns a ParseObject, but `fetchIfNeededInBackground` won't return the subclass, just ParseObject.  The documentation describes it so:

`public final <T extends ParseObject> void fetchIfNeededInBackground(GetCallback<T> callback)`

To me, that seems to indicate that it will give back a subclass of ParseObject according to the type of callback object you pass in.  On the other hand, `fetch` says:

`public <T extends ParseObject> T fetch()`

And I don't see how you can supply a subtype to that method.  Do I need to call a `fetch` method on an instance of `Bar` in order for this to work?  If so, how do I get a `Bar` from my `Foo`?  I think I could call `getParseObject`, create a new `Bar`, and copy the values from one to the other, but that's really gross and I'm hoping I don't have to shower every time I see this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with doing it a different way and then parse gave me a more helpful error message: the `Bar` subclass wasn't registered.  So if you can't figure out why you can't cast to your subclass, make sure it's registered, because the exception may not mention that as the cause.